# Trouble connecting to Postgres running in an EC2 instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am having some trouble connecting to a PSQL database in an EC2 instance. I know there are multiple questions here on SO going over this, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Here are all the configurations that I have done.

This is my `postgresql.conf` file. I've added the last on this file

```
# Directory for PostgreSQL sockets, lockfiles and stats tempfiles
d /run/postgresql 2775 postgres postgres - -
# Log directory
d /var/log/postgresql 1775 root postgres - -

listen_addresses = '*'
```

Here my `pg_hba.conf` file. I've added the last 2 lines on this file

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0              md5
host    all             all              ::/0                   md5
```

The inbound settings in my EC2s security group
[image]

I am trying to connect to the DB from a lambda function. The lambda is on the same security group, VPC and subnet as the EC2 instance.

Here is the lambda function

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
const { Client } = require('pg');  
const client = new Client();
let response = {};
try {
   await client.connect();
   await client.end();
   response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      result: "WooHoo connected to the DB"
  };
} catch (e) {
  response = {
  statusCode: 500,
  result: "Cant connect to DataBase" + e
  };
client.end();
}
return response;
};
```

I get the following response when I test the lambda

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "result": "Cant connect to DataBaseError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.29.67:5432"
}
```

172.31.29.67 is the private IP of the EC2 instance.

I am using the steps described [here](https://medium.com/@ly.lee/connecting-aws-lambda-node-js-to-redshift-or-postgresql-try-aws-lambda-layers-78e60c27f39b) to add a layer to the lambda to add 'pg'.

These are the environment variables I have set for the lambda function

[image]

Questions:

- Why is my DB refusing the connection?
- Can I configure the EC2 security group inbound such that only the Lambda can connect the the EC2 instance ?

Comment: That is a network error. Either the server is not listening on that port, or the IP address is wrong, or there is no route to the host, or there is a firewall somewhere.

Comment: I've added the configs to postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files and enabled traffic in my inbound settings and added my lambda function to (what I think is) the right VPC and security group. 

Have I missed anything? Or misconfigured something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was not editing the postgresql.conf file at all, but some other random file. Not sure how that happened. If you have similar issues, search for the postgresql.conf file by using the command

```
locate postgresql.conf
```

You are looking for a file that is at a location that looks something like

```
/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf
```

and then add this to file in the network connections.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

you will need to restart the psql service for the changes to take effect

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

The rest is the same as I have described in the question.